# 'Research on this topic is a gap at Berkeley'. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality-in-context

I'm now writing a cover letter where I explain how my work can contribute to academia and use this phrase:

> Although pockets of expertise in Eastern Europe are spread across
> departments, research on Eastern European art is a gap at Berkeley.

Is this sentence correct? Can something be a 'gap' somewhere?

Comment: It does not sound fluent or natural.  A "thing" is not normally considered a "gap", because a gap means an emptiness, a void, something missing.